# Advanced SQL Join one to multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In SQL Server 2008 I have a [Customers] Table
[Customer ID],[Name]
 1,Sam
 2,Rick

Another table [Payments] Having feilds
[Customer ID], [Amount]
1, 100
2, 200
1, 150

Now, how can I join these tables to show like this
[Customer ID],[Name],[Amount]
1, Sam, 100
2, Rick, 200
1, Sam, 150

I donno whether this question have already been asked or not. I couldn't find an appropriate answer.
Please note the fact that one customer might make multiple payments. That's exactly where I need help.
So can anyone help me?

I am a beginner in SQL. Brief explanations of answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ You already used the tag JOIN so you know what do to but I`ll let stackoverflow to work for me right?

Comment: FYI:  This is in no way an advanced topic, merely a simple `inner join`

Comment: I know join but my problem is that I have multiple entries of same ID in the 2nd table.

Comment: And?  That seems to be exactly what you want in your example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Customers].[CustomerID], [Customers].[Name], [Payments].[Amount]
FROM [Customers]
INNER JOIN [Payments] ON [Payments].[CustomerID] = [Customers].CustomerID]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Don't you mean `INNER JOIN [Payments] ON [Payments].[CustomerID] = [Customers].[CustomerID]`?  Don't just slap some code in the answer box, make sure it's right first

Comment: Thanks, Bobby.  I'm working on many different things at work right now as well :)